# javascript combine array and dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any good JavaScript hash(code/table) implementation out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225367/is-there-any-good-javascript-hashcode-table-implementation-out-there)

I want a data structure that I can query a key from in O(1), delete an element rather quickly and random sample from in O(1).

I thought of a Dictionary (for the key query) combined with Array (for sampling).
But is there a way to connect (pointer) between the 2?

for example: I want to delete an entry, given its key. so I can delete it easily from the dictionary, but how can I use the dictionary to splice it out of the Array?

edit:

```
var dict = {key1: "val1",key2:"val2"};
```

getting the item by key:

```
getKey = function(key){ return dict[key]; }
```

getting the item by index (which I want to change)

```
getIndex = function(ind) { return dict.values()[ind] }
```

the problem with the getIndex function is that .values() goes over all the dictionary and puts it in an array. and if the dictionary is large that is very expensive.

**Update:**
I forgot about this question and in the meanwhile I've solved it, so here's the solution:
We can use a dictionary and an array:
The array will hold all the keys of the dictionary
The dictionary will hold the keys as its keys and instead of the values a tuple of  where index is the index of this element's key in the array (a pointer back to the array of sort).
So this way the array points to the dictionary and the dictionary points back to the array.

Now the operations on the ds are as following:

**Insert(key,value):**
  push a new key to the array
  create a tuple 
  insert the tuple to the dictionary with key 'key'

**get(key):**
 return dictionary.get(key)

**remove(key):**
  remove elem from the dictionary
  switch between the last key in the array and our key (we have the pointer to our key)
  update the pointer in the dictionary to the key that was last and we've switched
  delete our key from the array

**randomSample(sampler):**
  sample the array with sampler (which can be uniform sampling for example).
  iterate over all the samples and return the values corresponding the keys from the dictionary

The full source code of the class is available: https://gist.github.com/shacharz/9807577

Comment: Can you post some code of what you got so far? Hard to imagine wht's being asked here without a sample...

Comment: This seems like it'd be a decent grad student homework problem, to prove that this request is impossible. :-)  (Maybe it's not; then it'd be a trick question!) Also I don't think it's really about JavaScript in particular.

Comment: Please post sample data and sample access. Just looking for an "ordered dictionary"?

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what you want to achieve with the random sample.
but from what i understood you're basically looking for a map that allows you to get hold of the list of values?

found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/868728/715236

Comment: Well basically I just want a dictionary with random-access (like an array). don't need order I just want to access values either by keys, or by an index.

Comment: @user1674942 What good is accessing a Map (or Dictionary) by "index" if there is No Ordering?

Comment: Let's say I want to uniformly random sample the Dictionary entries

Comment: @user1674942 Since the result desired is then an "[un]random sample" only, we can discard the `getIndex` function and merely have a `getValueForSomeUnknownKey` function?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't know if this solution passes your performance criteria but here it goes...
The core of the idea is to use the same dictionary to store both of these. There are some clear drawbacks including the holes in the index generated by deletes. Lookups should be quite quick, and this allows for a very good random lookup when using a good source of random data.

It's difficult to have your cake and eat it too. Definitely interested in other solutions to this.

```
var dict = {key1: "val1", 0:"key1", key2:"val2", 1:"key2"};
var COUNT = 1;

// inserts
function insertValue(dictionary, key, value) {
    if (typeof dictionary[key] === 'undefined') {    
        COUNT++;
        dict[key] = value;
        dict[COUNT] = key;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return;
}

// return an item by index
var index = 20;
var itemByIndex = dict[dict[index]];

// updates by index
dict[dict[index]] = newValue;

// return a "random" element
function getRandomItem (dictionary, maxIndex) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.rand() * maxIndex);
    var randomValue = dictionary[randomNumber];
    if (typeof randomValue === 'undefined') {
        return getRandomItem(dictionary, maxIndex);
    }
    return randomValue;
}

// deletes item by index
function deleteItemByIndex(dictionary, index) {
    delete dictionary[dictionary[index]];
    delete dictionary[index];
}
```